# Proving an identity related to hyperbolic rotations

Tags: matrices, rotations

I am working on the following exercise:

> Let
>
> $$r_t := \begin{pmatrix}
> 1 &0 &0 \\
> 0 &\cosh t & \sinh t \\
> 0 &\sinh t & \cosh t
> \end{pmatrix}.
> $$
> Show that for $M \in SO_{2,1}^+$ there is a rotation $\rho$ (in the common sense) around the $z$-axis and some $t \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $r_t \circ \rho \circ M \cdot (0,0,1)^T = (0,0,1)^T$.

Here are the definitions we are using in the lecture:

> $$I_{r,s} := diag(\underbrace{ 1,\ldots,1}_{\text{$r$ times}},\underbrace{ -1,\ldots,-1}_{\text{$s$ times}})$$
> $$SO_{r,s} := \{M \in M_n \mid M^TI_{r,s}M = I_{r,s} \text{ and } det(M) = 1 \}$$
> $$SO_{r,s}^+ := \{M \in M_n \mid M \in SO_{r,s} \text{ and } z > 0 \text{ for } (x,y,z)^T: = M\cdot(0,0,1)^T \}$$

I do not see how I could show that. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: they have $N= r_t \circ \rho \circ M$  which is in the same group. If $N \cdot (0,0,1)^T = (0,0,1)^T$  then $N$   is actually a rotation $\rho_2$   for some angle. Check it. All together, any $M$  satisfies $r_t \circ \rho \circ M = \rho_2,$  multiply onthe left by $\rho_3 $  to get $ \rho_3 \circ r_t \circ \rho M = I,$   having chosen $\rho_3 \rho_2 = I$  Inverting we get $M = \rho_4 r_s \rho_5$  where $s=-t$ That is the target, every isometry has a specific decomposition

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I do not understand why $N \cdot (0,0,1)^T = (0,0,1)^T$ implies that $N$ is a a rotation. I computed $N$ explicitely and tp see if it would make it clearer, but I still do not get it. Could you please explain this?

Comment: you have the right hand column of $N$   being that $(0,0,1)^T,$   then $N^T D N = D,$   where $D = I_{2,1} $

Comment: Sorry, but I still do not get it. I understand that $N \in SO_{2,1}^+$, since $r_t, \rho, M \in SO_{2,1}^+$. But then the condition $N^T I_{2,1} N = I_{2,1}$ follows from the fact that $N \in SO_{r,s}^+$, so what does the condition $N \cdot (0,0,1)^T = (0,0,1)^T$ have to do with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on pages 23 and 124 in Magnus, *Noneuclidean Tesselations and Their Groups.*

You asked for $M^T D M = D,$   where $D$ is the three by three diagonal matrix with diagonal elements $1,1,-1$ in that order.  For some real $a,b,c,d$   with $ad-bc=1,$  we get

$$
M = 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{1}{2}  \left( a^2 - b^2 - c^2 + d^2   \right)&ab+cd&\frac{1}{2}  \left( a^2 + b^2 - c^2 - d^2   \right) \\
ac+bd&ad+bc&ac-bd \\
\frac{1}{2}  \left( a^2 - b^2 + c^2 - d^2   \right)&ab-cd&\frac{1}{2}  \left( a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2   \right) \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$

Furthermore, all $M$  arise this way.   The reduction they are asking amounts to taking the two by two matrix
$ \left( \begin{array}{rr} a&b \\ c & d   \end{array}  \right)   $  in $SL_2 \mathbb R$ back to the identity,  in three steps.